# SQL : Sum of the Count of number of rows in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following column , i want to get the total count of unique rows next to each row . How would i do that ?

```
The Column i have   |  Col i want
52806                        9
52806                        9
52806                        9
53317                        9
54620                        9
54722                        9
54830                        9
54917                        9
54923                        9
54942                        9
54947                        9
54947                        9
```

i searched for the appropriate answer online i could not find it anywhere !!
I don't want to use group by clause because its a big query

Comment: You mean like `select count(distinct column) from mytable`?

Comment: if i use count it gives me 1 in every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
-- CROSS JOIN
SELECT A.[The Column],
       B.[Col you want]
FROM dbo.YourTable A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [The Column]) [Col you want]
            FROM dbo.YourTable) B
;
```

Comment: @sandeshbn weird. Well, the `CROSS JOIN` should work

Comment: the column i want is not in the database table , its the count that i want to add

Comment: @sandeshbn I don't get it. This answer gives you the otuput you wanted. You'll need to clarify your question

Comment: @Lamak : sorry my bad . Got it Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work

```
select T.TableColumn, COUNT(T.TableColumn) AS ComputedCol FROM GivenTable T GROUP BY T.TableColumn
```